# Dealing with ambiguous declarations in C++

Tags: c++, ambiguous

**In my header file I define:**

```
inline t_pair pair(int a, int b) { t_pair p; p.a = a; p.b = b; return p; }
```

But I get a compiler error "Reference to 'pair' is ambiguous".
Apparently there is a

```
struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY pair
```

defined in utility.cpp, which I do not include directly.

Is there a way to still use my pair function without renaming it?

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;` from your code.

Comment: I agree with @rightføld you probably have `std` namespace pollution and it is confusing your `pair` with `std::pair`.

Comment: Even though you don't want to, I would refactor the function to make_t_pair to align it with the std naming convention. c.f. std::make_pair()

Comment: This is compiles and runs without errors.
int FILE;
::FILE* fopen;
fopen=::fopen("file","rw");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can wrap your function declaration with another namespace or you can just use the `std::pair` class and avoid [reinventing the wheel](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel).

Also note that the `std::pair` class allows you to create pairs of generic types. So it's not limited to only pairs of type `int`. You can find an example of its usage [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/pair/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by putting your function declaration into a namespace:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    inline t_pair pair(int a, int b) { t_pair p; p.a = a; p.b = b; return p; }
}
```

And then calling it like `MyNamespace::pair (a, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably should) put your function in namespace, but, you actually should to remove `using namespace std` from your code, since there is class `pair` in std namespace. You can not include utility (where pair is defined), but it can be included by some other file.